# c# - Connect to Netsuite ODBC

Tags: c#, web-services, odbc, netsuite

I'm new to Netsuite and I'm trying to connect to Netsuite DB through ODBC but I don't know how to set the connection string.

I have a system DSN for Netsuite driver. How do I connect to the system DSN?

I tried to use Netsuite's web services but I don’t get all the data from "Accounts" table – for example, the column "IS_BALANCESHEET" is missing.

I need some help.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hope you meant the DSN instead of DNS

Comment: This may help you http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8ef97c/odbc-dsn-using-in-Asp-Net/